# Is there anything like a clustered index that can be created using a nullable column as part of the indexed columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Where have a large table without a primary key that has a unique index on three fields, two of which are nullable.

There is quite a lot of application code that relies on the value (or non-value) NULL meaning something, so we have to keep the nullable values for the columns and they are the key columns that would normally be a primary key / clustered index.

**Is there anything that can be done index-wise on /for these three fields?  We just upgraded the DB to SQL Server 2012.**

Even as nullable columns the rows will all contain unique values in these fields.

```
CREATE TABLE [troublesome].[table](
[AId] [int] NOT NULL,
[BNumber] [int] NULL,
[UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A clustered index *can* have nullable key columns. First, drop the unique non-clustered index, then:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX uq_c_tt
  ON dbo.troublesome_table(AId, BNumber, UserId);
```

I suspect you tried to create a primary key, not a clustered index? It's a common misconception (possibly because only one of each is allowed per table, and a primary key is clustered by default) but a primary key and clustered index are not the same thing. A clustered index doesn't have to be the primary key and the primary key does not have to be clustered.